# handling [Errno 111] Connection refused return by requests in flask

Tags: python, error-handling, flask, python-requests

I have my backend developed in java which does all kind of processing. And my frontend is developed using python's flask framework. I am using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to send a request and get a response from the apis present in java.

Following is the line in my code which does that:

```
req = requests.post(buildApiUrl.getUrl('user') + "/login", data=payload)
```

My problem is, sometimes when the tomcat instance is not running or there is some issue with java apis, I always get an error from requests as follows:

```
    ERROR:root:HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /MYAPP/V1.0/user/login (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahul/git/myapp/webapp/views/utils.py", line 31, in decorated_view
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/git/myapp/webapp/views/public.py", line 37, in login
    req = requests.post(buildApiUrl.getUrl('user') + "/login", data=payload)
  File "/home/rahul/git/myapp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/git/myapp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/git/myapp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/git/myapp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 438, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/git/myapp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 327, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /MYAPP/V1.0/user/login (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

I want to handle any such errors that I receive in my flask app so that I can give the necessary response on the web page instead of showing blank screen. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch the exception request.post raises using `try-except`:

```
try:
    req = requests.post(buildApiUrl.getUrl('user') + "/login", data=payload)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    # Handle exception ..
```